# Rotate $xyz$ by use of pitch and yaw around origin

Tags: matrices, rotations

I have a project for a game which uses pitch/yaw for the direction of a players head.
The pitch ranges from $0$ to $180$ and the yaw is $0$ to $360$.

Yaw modifies $X$ and $Z$, pitch modifies the $Y$, however I need to keep the $xyz$ at this distance from the origin $(0,0,0)$. So modifying the $Y$ means that the $X$ and $Z$ need to be modified in order to keep the $xyz$ this distance away from the origin.

I asked in the gaming community, and the large majority of replies came up with this.
https://github.com/md-5/SmallPlugins/blob/master/TestPlugin/src/main/java/net/md_5/TestPlugin.java#L101

The problem is, the $X$ and $Z$ curve inwards as the pitch approaches the upper and lower limits.
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Sphere_wireframe_10deg_6r.svg

I ask that you don't reply with the formulas found in Wikipedia, as I can't understand the more complex ones. But rather post it in a single line such as "$\cos(x)\cdot$(pitch + yaw)"

Comment: It will be good if you can define what is pitch and yaw

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to define a heading direction based on absolute pitch and yaw angles, then the code they gave you is correct, but they swapped Y and Z from your definition. This is what you'd want:

```
    double sRadians = Math.toRadians( yaw );
    double tRadians = Math.toRadians( pitch );
    double x = radius * Math.cos( sRadians ) * Math.sin( tRadians );
    double y = radius * Math.cos( tRadians );
    double z = radius * Math.sin( sRadians ) * Math.sin( tRadians );
```

Which is just specifying a vector of length `radius` in [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) given by `yaw` and `pitch` in degrees, as you specified.

Also, could you please clarify:

> The problem is, the X and Z curve inwards as the pitch approaches the upper and lower limits.

You need this behavior in order for the vector to have a fixed length. It's how the coordinate system works.

If you actually want to rotate a given vector given pitch and yaw angles, then you need to specify an order in which the two rotations will take place, as 3D rotations are not commutative.

**EDIT**: now that the context is clear, just make:

```
double textDistance = /* distance to text relative to the player */;
double textPitch = /* pitch of the text relative to player's pitch */;
double textYaw = /* yaw of the text relative to player's yaw */;
double sRadians = Math.toRadians( playerYaw + textYaw );
double tRadians = Math.toRadians( playerPitch + textPitch );
double x = textDistance * Math.cos( sRadians ) * Math.sin( tRadians );
double y = textDistance * Math.cos( tRadians );
double z = textDistance * Math.sin( sRadians ) * Math.sin( tRadians );
```

Then add $(x,y,z)$ to the player's coordinate to get the text's coordinate.

Comment: Actually they swap it back in the returns.
The issue is that, that bit of math returns this
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Sphere_wireframe_10deg_6r.svg

When what I want is this
http://static5.depositphotos.com/1040226/463/i/950/depositphotos_4630887-Sphere-grid.jpg

Comment: @libraryaddict But that's a spherical distortion of square grid. It doesn't seem to apply to the idea of pitch and yaw you mentioned. Can you be more specific about what the application is, and why you are using those two visuals to explain it? It seems to me that you are trying to get Y given X and Z, without using pitch and yaw angles. In that case, you want $Y = \sqrt{R^2 - X^2 - Y^2}$, where $R$ is the desired radius.

Comment: https://gfycat.com/LameAmazingDrongo

The text is positioned using the xyz added onto the players position. Ideally the text will remain at the same location on his screen. Which requires it to be the same distance so the text doesn't shrink or grow. And the pitch/yaw to be used to keep it relative to the players new view.

That gfycat was created to demostrate to someone else that the example given in the original post doesn't work

Comment: @libraryaddict Oooh, now I get what you are trying to do. How are you specifying the coordinates of those labels before transforming them? If you are using spherical coordinates, then you can just add the pitch and yaw of the head to the spherical angles that define the position of the label. No need for rotation matrices.

Comment: I start with a xyz which is the text position relative to the lpayer and the players current pitch/yaw.

Comment: @libraryaddict All right. Check the edit to my original answer, then.

Comment: https://gfycat.com/IncomparableSnoopyCaracal As you can see. The problem I mentioned is occurring with your edit. The text shouldn't be curving into the center of the screen when I look up or down